# Cannot mount external HDD because of checksum error on a specific file

Tags: mount, 16.10, external-hdd, checksums

I'm getting the following error when trying to mount my external HDD.

[image]

How to solve such an error? I gave a quick search, but didn't find anything helpful yet.

Getting the same error if I try to mount it in the command line:

```
$ lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
sdc      8:32   0   4,6T  0 disk 
├─sdc2   8:34   0   4,6T  0 part 
└─sdc1   8:33   0   200M  0 part 
...
$ sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdc2 /media/exfat
FUSE exfat 1.2.4
ERROR: 'Joy To the World - 24122016, 21.53.aif' has
invalid checksum (0xd47e != 0xd37e).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I had another machine running macOS I mounted the external hard disk on my MacBook and deleted that file.

Seems like that was a file which was corrupted somehow.

Then it worked.

Comment: The file that I wanted has got corrupted. Is there any other way apart from connect to MacOS and deleting the file/directory?
Is there a method with fsck?

Comment: @mythicalcoder To be honest, I have no idea... Maybe you can ask here or on UNIX & Linux.